# List all points within radius using Hive

Tags: hive, gis, esri

I have a table as follows:

```
id_center|latitude_of_center|longitude_of_center|id_point|latitude_of_point|longitude_of_point
```

The table is many millions of rows

I'm trying to get the output which would show for each id_center which id_points are within a 5 mile radius, and how far the distance is, sorted in descending order.  Each row is fully populated, so each id_center has all possible id_point in separate rows.  Here's what I've tried thus far, and I'm just getting null results:

```
hive> add jar /home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar;
Added [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/esri-geometry-api.jar]
hive> add jar /home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar;
Added [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/home/me/gis-tools-for-hadoop/samples/lib/spatial-sdk-hadoop.jar]
hive> create temporary function ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84 AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84';
OK
Time taken: 0.014 seconds
hive> create temporary function ST_SetSRID AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_SetSRID';
OK
Time taken: 0.008 seconds
hive> create temporary function ST_LineString AS 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_LineString';

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(latitude_of_center, longitude_of_center, latitude_of_point, longitude_of_point), 4326)) <= 8046.72
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ST_LineString, you need longitude first, then latitude - (X,Y) order.
(As also discussed on GIS-SE https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178950/hive-gis-st-geodesiclengthwgs84-not-returning-expected-distance)

Comment: I did flip the lat/long values, and the query seems to have worked, but did not return the distance as a field.  I think I need to add something to the HQL statement to create that as a field...Any ideas on what has to happen?

Comment: Instead of `select *` try `select ST_GeodesicLength...`

Answer (score 0):

I used `ST_Point` inside `ST_LineString` when worked on similar task. Check this option in [docs](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Constructors#st_linestring).
In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(array(ST_Point(longitude_of_center, latitude_of_center), ST_Point(longitude_of_point, latitude_of_point))), 4326)) <= 8046.72;
```